# Unity3D: Position objects relative to Vuforia Image marker im multiple scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

I have two scenes:

Scene1: User has to track Image marker.

Scene2: Display Objects relative to the image marker scanned in Scene1.

In Scene1 i attached "Vuforia Behaviour Script" to the MRKT camera. In Scene2 im just using the out of the box camera from MRTK (wihtout Vuforia Behaviour Script).

Is there any way to store the position data to archive this?

Im using Hololens2 With MRTK

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spatial Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/coordinate-systems#spatial-anchors) to track the special point in the world. When you are using this technology, you should note the locations where you create anchors should have stable visual features(that is, features that don't change often). For example, the physical surface you mentioned Vuforia image marker is not a good point to create anchors. However, it would be good practice to place anchors where they have stable visual features around Vuforia image markers and record the relative position of the image marker from the anchor.

If you are new to the Spatial Anchor, you can start from here: [Spatial Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/spatial-anchors)